# Particle in a box - standing wave

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation

Why can't we consider that a particle in a box is an example of a standing wave?
The ends are fixed by the fact that the potential outside is infinite. The only difference being that it is a de Broglie wave, and the amplitude is the probability density. So a quantum particle, because it has wave-like properties, behaves in this box as an ordinary wave constrained to exist between one end to another.

---

Edit:
Perhaps I should rephrase the question:
**Is there a problem with considering that a particle in a box is an example of a standing wave?**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Who says we can't? It is common knowledge.

Comment: While it is true that we can, I wouldn't say that quantum mechanics is common knowledge. ;)

Comment: Elementary quantum mechanics is taught to tens of thousands of undergraduates every single year. It is pretty common knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually the definition of a standing wave. In quantum mechanics, the standing wave solutions are those whose square modulus does not change in time. Namely, the eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian are those whose square modulus does not evolve with time since the wavefunction itself only picks up a phase factor. This means that the probability density for a particle is not changing as a function of time, and you can consider all of the measurable artifacts of the system as stationary.